# C code convert to C++ sha1 issue

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char ibuf[] = "trysha";
    unsigned char obuf[20];

    SHA1(ibuf, strlen(ibuf), obuf);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", obuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I got some error with this code..

```
sha.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sha.cpp:10:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/string.h:399:15: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘size_t strlen(const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Just cast them using `static_cast<type>` to the correct type.

Comment: `strlen` is just silly if you already know how long your string is. Just use `sizeof ibuf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen()` wants a `const char *`, or at least a `char*`, the problem is that you're giving to it an `unsigned char*`. You should do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main()
{
    char ibuf[] = "trysha";
    unsigned char obuf[20];

    SHA1(ibuf, strlen(ibuf), obuf);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", obuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If SHA1 expects an `unsigned char*` as first argument, you may have to cast `ibuf`: `SHA1(static_cast<unsigned char*>(ibuf), strlen(ibuf), obuf);`

By the way you don't need `strlen()`, you can replace it by this:
`SHA1(ibuf, sizeof(ibuf), obuf);`

Answer (score 0):

It tells you exactly what is wrong -- `strlen` doesn't accept `unsigned char*`, but rather plain `const char*`. According to 3.9.1.1 of the C++98 standard, `signed char`, `unsigned char` and `char` are distinct types and you cannot convert them explicitly.

Why are you using `unsigned char` for C-style strings anyway?